# How to apply org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook from command line?

Tags: org-mode, script

This problem is so convoluted that maybe I should call it a puzzle...

---

On the Unix shell command line, I can convert TSV (tab-separated-values) input to org-mode table format with this perl one-liner:

```
perl -lpe 's/(?:^|$|\t)/|/g'
```

So, for example, I can write something like

```
<<<pipeline producing TSV rows>>> | perl -lpe 's/(?:^|$|\t)/|/g' > mytable.org
```

The contents of mytable.org would be a valid org-mode table, but it would not be nicely formatted.

For example, if `<<<pipeline producing TSV rows>>>` produced the following

```
1   ABCDEFG
234567  HIJKLMNO
890123  P
```

...the contents of `mytable.org` would be

```
|1|ABCDEFG|
|234567|HIJKLMNO|
|890123|P|
```

To format it nicely, I could

1. open `mytable.org` with Emacs;
2. set the major mode to org-mode (if it doesn't happen by default);
3. hit `C-c C-c`, aka `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c-hook`, which has the effect of reformatting the table so that the delimiters line up; and
4. save the file;

...after which the contents of `mytable.org` would look like this

```
|      1 | ABCDEFG  |
| 234567 | HIJKLMNO |
| 890123 | P        |
```

---

My question is, how can I perform this reformating operation from the command line, without having to start an interactive Emacs session?

More specifically, is there a way to implement a pipeline component, *that uses Emacs*, and that I can insert right before the output redirection `> mytable.org`, like this

```
<<<pipeline producing TSV rows>>> | perl -lpe 's/(?:^|$|\t)/|/g' \
    | format-org-table > mytable.org
```

...that it would achieve the same final form of `mytable.org` as shown earlier?  The goal here is to avoid the need to "manually" open `mytable.org` with Emacs, then hit `C-c C-c`, etc.

Comment: Take a look at using Emacs in noninteractive [batch mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Batch-Mode.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
;;; csv-to-org-table.el --- Convert CSV to Org table  -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;;; Commentary:

;; Example:
;; 
;; ~ $ echo "a\tb\n1\t2" | emacs --batch -l csv-to-org-table.el
;; | a | b |
;; | 1 | 2 |

;;; Code:

(insert-file-contents "/dev/stdin")

(if (zerop (buffer-size))
    (kill-emacs)
  (require 'org)
  (org-table-convert-region (point-min) (point-max))
  (princ (buffer-string)))

;;; csv-to-org-table.el ends here
```

If you prefer `format-org-table` to `emacs --batch -l csv-to-org-table.el`, you can create an Emacs Lisp script or shell alias/function.

---

However, it is better to use a proper programming language and implement `org-table-convert-region` from scratch, I don't think it will be difficult.

Comment: Thank you!  Out of curiosity, is there a problem with replacing the `(if (zerop (buffer-size)) ...` with `(unless (zerop (buffer-size)) ...`, getting rid of the `(kill-emacs)`, and putting the remaining expressions in a `(progn ...)`?

Comment: @kjo No problem. It is actually better. The above code is ported from https://github.com/xuchunyang/emacs.d/blob/master/bin/csv-to-org-table, somehow `(kill-emacs)` is used.